# Disable select2 dropdown with knockout binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have an MVC Razor project and in my view i have one `Html.TextBoxFor` with `data-bind="disable: setRoot"`. This `input` is used by Select2 jquery plugin.
My problem is that the `disable` binding is not working properly.
This is my code:

```
<div class="control-label">Category</div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><label><input data-bind="checked: setRoot" type="checkbox"> root</label>
                        </div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Create.IdCategory, new { id = "QuickSearchMainCategory", data_bind = "disable: setRoot, value: model.Create.IdCategory", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
```

and my js:

```
self.setRoot = ko.observable(true);

            self.beRoot = ko.computed(function() {
                if (self.setRoot() === true) {
                    self.model.IdCategory(self.model.IdRootCategory());

                } else {
                    self.model.IdCategory(null);
                }
            });

$("#QuickSearchMainCategory").select2({
                placeholder: "Category search",
                minimumInputLength: 3,
                width: 'resolve',
                ajax: {
                    url: urlQuickSearchCategory,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true,
                    quietMillis: 400,
                    data: function(term, page) {
                        var data = {
                            term: term
                        };
                        return data;
                    },
                    results: function(data, page) {
                        return { results: data };
                    }
                },
                dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
                formatResult: function(item) { return item.id + " - " + item.label; },
                formatSelection: function(item) { return item.id + " - " + item.label; },
                escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
            });
```

If i inspect the html, the disable is working but not with the entire select2 elements but only with the input with the id `QuickSearchMainCategory`.
What do i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 doesnt work with the 'disabled' binding because you have to explicitly tell select2 to disable itself using its built in function.

You have to use this function to disable/enable it:

```
$('#QuickSearchMainCategory').select2('disable');
$('#QuickSearchMainCategory').select2('enable');
```

Youll have to do this in your ko viewmodel since just setting the disabled HTML attribute is not enough.

Comment: When disabled select2 the value is not sent to the mvc post. How to do it?

Comment: Disabled and form fields with CSS style of display:none are never sent with a HttpPost. Just enable the field or use a hidden input in your form instead.

Comment: I found how to do it, "Disabled" or "Enable" = false, all of them makes MVC to ignore the value. But I used  .select2('readonly', true) this made the field disabled on screen but MVC received the value!!